# Where are fonts determined besides System Settings and my browser?

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, settings, audacity

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04. Two places where the font sizes used in an application are determined  are the Fonts section of Appearance within System Settings and the browser I'm using (plus the application itself in some cases). When I'm having font problems,where else should I look?  (This question is a generalization of one I asked yesterday about Audacity.)

Looking at it another way, how does Audacity decide which font(s) to use? This question applies both to the Help files and to the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

[fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/) is an important component behind the scenes. You can for instance run this command:

```
fc-match -s | head -10
```

to get an idea which of your installed fonts are prioritized by `fontconfig`. That in turn is primarily determined by the files in `/etc/fonts/conf.d`.